# problem with executing a backend sqlite3 in my frontend tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, tkinter-entry

i'm making a simple program which i can insert or save a data in UI then view the inserted data in tkinter but the problem is, i don't really know how to do it in my frontend code. thanks in advance
`import datab` is my backend which is  in the `sql`.

```
from tkinter import *
import datab


class main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        but = Button(self, text="input", command=self.butin)
        but.grid()
        but2 = Button(self, text="output", command=self.butout)
        but2.grid()

    def butin(self):
        textV1 = StringVar()
        g = Toplevel()
        inbut = Button(g, text="save", command=self.add_d)
        inbut.grid()
        enbox = Entry(g, textvariable=textV1)
        enbox.grid()

    def butout(self):
        h = Toplevel()
        shobut = Button(h, text="show", command=self.view_D)
        shobut.grid()
        sholab = Label(h, text="")
        sholab.grid()

    def add_d(self):
        datab.schedinsert(self.enbox.get())

    def view_d(self):
        datab.schedview(self.sholab.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    g = main(root)
    g.grid()
    g.mainloop()
```

i think this is the problem, i'm not sure if my `def add_d(self):` and
`def view_d(self):` is right.

```
def add_d(self):
    datab.schedinsert(self.enbox.get())

def view_d(self):
    datab.schedview(self.sholab.get())
```

and the error that showing up

```
*File "C:/Users/win8.1/PycharmProjects/data/basedatabase/mainprogram.py", line 
30, in add_d
datab.schedinsert(self.enbox.get())
AttributeError: 'main' object has no attribute 'enbox'
File "C:/Users/win8.1/PycharmProjects/data/basedatabase/mainprogram.py", line 
33, in view_d
datab.schedview(self.sholab.get())
AttributeError: 'main' object has no attribute 'sholab'*
```

Comment: What sort of help do you need? As written this question is too broad. Can you be more specific about the type of help you need?

Comment: in my frame i assigned two buttons which is the input and output 'button' where when you clicked it they will bring you into a window, in input window there is a 'entry' and a 'button' which is my actual problem as to how to save the text data in 'entry' , while the output window has a button and a label where the button purpose is to show the data collected in the input window or rather to show the save data in the form of 'label' and that's the second problem or where i needed help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information, and please remove any code that's not necessary to reproduce the problem. For example, do we really need that sql code, or can the problem be reproduced with print statements?

Comment: this should do it right?

Comment: The code isn't runnable, so no, it's not a proper [mcve].  The error seems to be telling you exactly what's wrong, however.  It says your `main` object has no attribute named `sholab`, and there's nothing in the code you've posted that creates an attribute with that name. Are you aware of the difference between object attributes and local variables?

Comment: Ya please edit the code so its runnable @JoferSykes

Comment: Have you eddited it yet?